# Google Drive Header Auth with an API_KEY instead of ACCESS_TOKEN

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Is it possible to use Google Header Auth with an API_KEY?

At the moment we are downloading files using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={our API key}
```

We want to migrate to using HTTP Header auth like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

The first method uses our own API_KEY from Google Cloud Console.

The second method uses an ACCESS_TOKEN created by the user authenticating with the app with oAuth.

Is it possible to use our API_KEY for HTTP Auth? Or do we have to use the users ACCESS_TOKEN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- API key grants you access to public data only.
- An access token is an authorized token which gives an application access to user data.

They are two different things.

The authorization header is used for sending authorization bearer tokens, access tokens to the server to authorize a request.

No you can not send an api key as a authorization header as it is not a bearer token.   You need to authenticate your users using Oauth2 in order to get access to their data, which will give you an access token and the ability to add that as a authorization header and request access to download the users file.

Comment: In addition to your answer I'd like to reference the [basic steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#basicsteps) when accessing a Google API

Comment: @JoseVasquez be my guest i have no objections to your improving the answer with that link :)